# Append filename with text from a specific textfile

Tags: linux, backup, sed

need some help.

I have a file called domoticz.backup.tar.gz
I allso have a file called History.txt that in the first line says Version 3.4834 (March 2nd 2016)

I would like to add the 3.4834 to the filename right before the extension do be able to identify what version the backup comes from. Ofc the numbers will change but I am counting on the layout of the file to be intact.

If anyone have a beter idee howto add current version to filename I would be happy to.

I have tried some with sed but gets nowhere.

Comment: You are asking us to write the entire process? Assuming you are using bash for the backups and inserting version into History.txt, I'm sure you can do it with Sed. http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed

Answer (score 1):

This will print the version number:

```
awk '{print $2; exit}' history.txt
```

This will rename the file:

```
F='your gzip tar file name'
mv $F $(basename $F.tar.gz).$(awk '{print $2; exit}' history.txt).tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to **head** the first line of the history, then **cut** the second field of its output to have the version.
Now only the **m**o**v**ing of domoticz.backup.tar.gz to domoticz.backup.$VERSION.tar.gz is left to do.